# Is it possible to write to mongodb console in javascript execution?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I'm learning about map-reduce functionality of mongodb. My first tests doesn't work as I expected and I want to know how is it working.

Is there **any way to write to mongodb console from javascript functions** so I can inspect it?

I tried `console.log("...")` but it doesn't work.

I will ask later about my tests if there isn't any way to do it.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

You have to use '`print( "anything .." )`' or `printjson` to display objects.

```
andrey@andrey:~$ mongo
MongoDB shell version: 2.0.2
connecting to: test
> object = { "name" : "any name .." , "key" : "value" }
{ "name" : "any name ..", "key" : "value" }
> printjson ( object )
{ "name" : "any name ..", "key" : "value" }
> print ( "hello world" )
hello world
>
```

Comment: I'm on Mac and this worked. If it's not working, it's because you're doing something else wrong. Double-check your file paths, permissions, etc.

Answer (score 7):

I guess from map/reduce functions you need to insert your *debug* messages into some logs collection:

```
var map = function() {
  //some staff here
};

var reduce = function(key, values) {
  db.mr_logs.insert({message: "Message from reduce function"});
  //some staff here
};


res = db.items.mapReduce(map, reduce,{ query : {}, out : 'example1' })
```

After this you can find your debug results in `mr_logs` collection.

```
db.mr_logs.find();
```

As for `print` it seems not printing output to console when you are in map or reduce functions.

Answer (score 5):

there is a super easy workaround in map-reduce environment.

[How to get print output for debugging map/reduce in Mongoid](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13963719/1654314)

Answer (score -2):

You can just write the name of the function / object like so:

```
>fn = function (){return12;}
>fn
function (){return12;}
>
```

Try it here: http://try.mongodb.org/