# How to get print output for debugging map/reduce in Mongoid?

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, mongoid, mongoid3

I'm writing a map/reduce operation with Mongoid 3.0. I'm trying to use the `print` statement to debug the JS functions. This is a [troubleshooting suggestion from the MongoDB docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/map-reduce/#troubleshooting-map-reduce-operations), e.g.:

```
reduce = %Q{
   function(user_id, timestamps) {
      var max = 0;
      timestamps.forEach(function(t) {
        var diff = t.started_at - t.attempted_at;
        if (diff > max) { max = diff; }
      });
      print(user_id + ', ' + max);
      return max;
    };
  }

 MyCollection.all.map_reduce(map, reduce).to_a
```

Unfortunately the output from the `print` statement shows up neither on the console nor on the log--it seems that this is suppressed somewhere between the DB, the driver, Moped or any of the intervening layers. Is there a way to turn this on?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Per the poster's comment, the first step is to make sure you are looking at the `mongod` server log. The easiest way to do this locally is by visiting the little-known HTTP interface to `mongod`: `http://localhost:28017`. This will work even if the server is not installed in its default location and, therefore, the log will not be in the default OS-specific location, e.g, `/usr/local/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log` on Mac OS X. 
See [the docs](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Http+Interface) for how to access this in non-standard deployment environments.

If that doesn't solve your problem, you'll have to go deeper into debugging MongoDB M/R, which is tricky for several reasons:

1. M/R jobs execute in a JS scope that is isolated from the rest of the DB
2. M/R jobs cannot write to anything other than the M/R output documents
3. The logger in MongoDB has discretion over what to emit to the logging stream

Here are my suggestions based on our extensive use of Mongo M/R in production:

**Increase the logging level**

Suddenly, some of the previously invisible `print` output will show up. Do it one level at a time until you start seeing it.

```
use admin
db.runCommand( { setParameter: 1, logLevel: 2 } )
```

Log levels vary from 0 to 5. See [setParameter](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/setParameter/). You can also do this at server startup with -v, -vv, ..., -vvvvv.

**Increase the profiling level to max (2)**

I've found this useful, especially when combined with a high log level as it provides data exhaust (the profiling collection) that can be programmatically inspected. See [the docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/manage-the-database-profiler/).

If you are running a very big M/R job, this may negatively affect performance.

**Piggyback debug output through M/R**

The idea is simple: add an array of objects with whatever debugging info you need, say in the `_debug` field, to all emitted documents and filter + concatenate as you see fit in the reduce phase. This way, the `_debug` arrays will end up in your output collection. You can even index them if you want to quickly find a particular problem.

Hope this helps. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for these suggestions. As it turns out, the answer is simple. I found a hint on the Mongoid Google Group. See my own answer below.

Comment: @WolframArnold Oh, I thought you were already looking at the `mongod` log.

Comment: sorry for the confusion. I was talking about the Rails log and Rails console. I'm using the Mongoid document adapter. Thanks for the effort.

Comment: I use Mongoid also. Lots of voodoo there, esp with the new driver. I updated my answer with info on how to see the log through the browser in an OS and installation-independent manner as well as for remote servers that have this enabled, e.g., in a private network. Normal file access to the logs may not work there.

Comment: Ok, I'll give you the credit for the remote situation. Although the local file access that I came up with was what solved my immediate problem. Thanks for the detail.

Answer (score 13):

It turns out the `print` statements logs to the MongoDB server log. On OSX, that is `/usr/local/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log`

Comment: This worked for me `tail -f /usr/local/var/log/mongodb/output.log`

Comment: combining this with a pipe and a grep helped me filter out the noise! thx!

    $ tail -f /usr/local/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log | grep 'mystuff'

Comment: I am using OSX too but my log file is empty. Do I need to switch on anything in config file etc.?